# QuickTime 7 pro on Mojave

Tags: video, quicktime, mojave

Is anyone here knowledgeable about whether QuickTime 7 (Pro) will still run on macOS Mojave?

QT7 is 32 bit and while Mojave still seems to allow 32 bit apps, I am wondering if the QT Media Framework on which the player is based is still included in Mojave (or at least still possible to install), not just for the player but also for third party apps that haven't moved on to AVFoundation yet.

Have any Mojave beta testers maybe tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. QuickTime 7 Pro still works on Mojave ¹
2. **/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework** still exists

If you're looking for more information, I'll need something a little more specific.

I hope that helps.

---

¹ more specifically:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X   
ProductVersion: 10.14   
BuildVersion:   18A347e
```

(aka “Mojave Public Beta 4”)

Answer (score 3):

when i click to change chapter it shuts down in Mojave, but that is the only issue so far